# ubuntu 14.04 login password reentering problem

Tags: 14.04, login, password

When i start to OS, enter the password, and a little bit second, it want to enter password again. 
If i enter wrong password, it warn me to invalid password, but i enter right password, it stay to want password.

> Note: it happens after i install nvidia driver manually.
>   i follow the instruction below video:
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZ-r3gS38RU

i stop the lightdm service while installing driver? can it cause this error?